# Dynamically added elements don't wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my plug-in I need to wrapp all sidebar's children in a div to let them overflow but if those elements are loaded dynamically the function does not work and I don't know either how to make it work.

The code is:

```
<div class="sidebar">
</div>

var $sidebar = $( '.sidebar' );

$sidebar.load( 'external-page.ext' );

$sidebar.MyPlugin();

$.fn.MyPlugin = function() {
    this.wrapInner( '<div />' );
});
```

If those elements are not loaded dynamically there is no problem.

Firstly the code was:

```
$sidebar.wrapInner( '<div/>' );
```

and this just works fine if elemens are not loaded dynamically, so I tried this way:

```
var children = $sidebar.children();

$( document ).on( 'load', children, function() {
    $( this ).wrapAll( '<div />' );
});
```

but, of course it does not work.
Can you please help me?

I thought that [this rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122514/dynamically-added-elements-dont-trigger-the-animation) would have worked this time too but it didn't. What did I mistake?

You can find the whole code [here](https://github.com/dcdeiv/simple-sidebar/blob/master/jquery.simplesidebar.js).
And a demo [here](http://dcdeiv.github.io/simple-sidebar/dev/)

**MORE DETAILS**

I want to handle this issue from the inside, not from the outside! I don't know if users will load content dinamically or not. that's the point.
So there is a way to handle this issue inside the plugin and not outside?

Comment: not sure if this helps @dcdeiv but tried to set up a fiddle which should demonstrate the problem may a little different: http://jsfiddle.net/82ptezgL/ result should be after click to show `hello hello` with `background-color:red;`

Comment: @caramba probably I miss the point, is this what are you looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/82ptezgL/1/ ?

Comment: @IrvinDominin thank you for you comment, it kinda is :) but need to add the wrapInner outside the load function. the element gets loaded from somewhere and I want to manipulate it from somewhere else..

Comment: @caramba but in your fiddle the wrapInner is fired before the click so the element not exist in that moment. If you execute the wrapInner in a next moment (eg in another click) it'll work. Can you provide your specific contest?

Comment: @IrvinDominin thanks for your time and effort. in words: I have a gallery loading and adding elements to the DOM. Now when that is done I would like to change some of those elements (add others). I have a `gallery.ready()` but that doenst works

Comment: can u please setup a working fiddle that explains the error more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

**From the manual**

http://api.jquery.com/load/

> Callback Function
>
> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.

Try the following code and see if this works:

```
$sidebar.load( 'external-page.ext', function() { $sidebar.MyPlugin(); } );
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer, already trid `load` but didn't work. added a fiddle above where the question is. could you have a try there `$(window).load(function(){});` included

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1dq8puyk/ here it works fine, (it will wrap .sidebar div, if you want to to wrap the inner elements, then you should call .MyPlugin on the inner elements)

Comment: Well, since I cannot control what users do, I want to handle this issue from the inside, not from the outside! I don't know if users will load content dinamically or not. that's the point.

Comment: you could still ask for a class or jquery selector from the users, to select the inner elements., in the config of your plugin

Answer (score 0):

[**`$.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) makes an **ajax call** to load the data ,

So there is a possibility that your `this.wrapInner( '<div />' )` method has invoked before any data is loaded inside the `div.sidebar`.
Make sure `this.wrapInner( '<div />' )` is called after all data has been loaded successfully using the complete callback.

[**`$.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) trigger callback for each div ,call your plugin from callback

```
$sidebar.load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/vikrant47/ncagab2y/1/show/', function () {
            $(this).MyPlugin();
        }    
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/1dq8puyk/2/)

**OR**

If you are using [**`$.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) only to load inside multiple elements then you could probably use one of the more powerful jQuery ajax methods (i.e., get() or post() or ajax()).

```
$.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net/vikrant47/ncagab2y/1/show/', {}, function(data) {
        $sidebar.html(data).MyPlugin();
    });
```

### [DEMO using $.get() Method](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/1dq8puyk/4/)

**UPDATE**-

**Answer to the comment-**

You should not have to worry about weather user gonna call your plugin like this `$sidebar.load(...).MyPlugin()`.User must be aware enough about how to handle `asynchronous` methods.

You can not make your plugin work until there is some data inside **`div.slider`**
but ,you can add ajax loading functionality inside your plugin like -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function (options) {
        var $elem=this;
        var init = function () {
            options.load = $.extend({}, $.fn.MyPlugin.defaultOptions.load, options.load);
            load();
        }
       //adding load method to load data dynamically
        var load = function () {
            if (!options.load.url) {
                alert("url can not be empty");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: options.load.url,
                    type: options.load.type,                    
                    data: options.load.data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        options.load.success.call(this, response);
                        $elem.html(response).wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"/>');//wrap after data has been loaded successfully
                    },
                    error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("error occured" + textStatus + " ," + errorThrown)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        init();
    }
    $.fn.MyPlugin.defaultOptions = {
        load: {
            tye: "get",
            data: {},
            success: function () {}
        }
    };
```

Now use your plugin like-

```
    var $sidebar = $('.sidebar');
    $sidebar.MyPlugin({
        load: {
            url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/vikrant47/ncagab2y/1/show/'
        }
    });
});
```

### [DEMO with load](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/1dq8puyk/6/)

Comment: I want to handle this issue from the inside, not from the outside! I don't know if users will load content dinamically or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding adding below piece to plugin . Added at lines **84 - 110** at [gist](https://gist.github.com/guest271314/eb53575a655c9575ec02) .

```
            var target = $sidebar.get(0);

            // create an observer instance
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                    // do stuff when
                    // `childList` modified
                    // i.e.g., 
                    $.each(mutation.addedNodes, function (k, v) {
                        $(v)
                        .wrapInner('<div data-' 
                        + dataName 
                        + '="sub-wrapper"></div>')
                    })

                });
            });

            // configuration of the observer:
            var _config = {
                childList: true
            };

            // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
            observer.observe(target, _config);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/s5wzptc8/

See [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: This looks verry interesting, checking back when I got some more time. dear guest, thank you for your answer!